# How to integrate FormFlow and QnA dialogs in a single bot

Tags: botframework, bots, formflow, azure-qna-maker

How to integrate FormFlow and QnA dialogs in a simple bot. I'm not able to call FormFlow context once QnA is completed. If there are any samples for the same, then please share.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use QnA and FormFlow, create a dialog QnADialog and you can send all your messages first to the root dialog from there you can call your QnA Dialog like

```
var qnadialog = new QnADialog();
var messageToForward = await message;
await context.Forward(qnadialog, ResumeAfterQnA, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None);
```

Once th QnADilalog is executed, it will call the ResumeAfterQnA and there you can call your FormFlow Dialog.

```
        private async Task ResumeAfterQnA(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> results)
        {
                SampleForm form = new SampleForm();
                var sampleForm = new FormDialog<SampleForm>(form, SampleForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
                context.Call(sampleForm, RootDialog.SampleFormSubmitted);

        }
```

You need to have a SampleFormSubmitted method that will be called after you form is submitted.

```
    private async Task SampleFormSubmitted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SampleForm> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = await result;
            context.Done(true);
        } 
        catch (FormCanceledException<SampleForm> e)
        {
            string reply;
            if (e.InnerException == null)
            {
                reply = $"You quit. Maybe you can fill some other time.";
            }
            else
            {
                reply = $"Something went wrong. Please try again.";
            }
            context.Done(true);
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to start of from a Luis template. 
Then make a specific Intent to start the Form. 
Then you can have an empty Luis Intent of ”” and even ”None” and you put your QnA there. 
That way the Qna will be on the background LUIS will give you great flexibility to trigger a specific dialogue with intents

Here is an example

http://www.garypretty.co.uk/2017/03/26/forwarding-activities-messages-to-other-dialogs-in-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: "One approach is to start of from a Luis template" so you will spend money on calling LUIS for nothing? What's the interest here?